# Redirect Url with parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess

What do I need to add to my .htaccess to redirect

`example.com/4711`
to 
`example.com/en/sponsor/!/4711`
or

`www.example.com/4190`
to 
`www.example.com/en/sponsor/!/4190

The numbers can range from 1 to 9999999

The solution should also work for http and https (default is https).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should at least be including what you've tried in the question...

However, the following should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]{1,7})$ /en/sponsor/!/$1 [NE,R,L]
```